# Nexus 3K VPC and active active solution

Tags: cisco-nx-os

I have 2x N3K-C3064PQ-10GX.

Each n3k has 2x 10G LACP to the same upstream router and 2x 10G LACP downlink to my access switch.

I have run VPC between my n3k and I have 50 vlan with same config on both n3k.

I am announcing 85.123.x.x/24 with no prepeding and such things on both nexus to my upstream router, so in this case some traffic reach my network from Nexus A and some of them reach me From Nexus B but in this case %80-90 of my traffic are reaching me from n3k B.

Here is my vpc config for n3k A :

```
vpc domain 1
  peer-switch
  role priority 20
  system-priority 120
  peer-keepalive destination 172.x.x.111 source 172.16.x.110
  peer-gateway
  auto-recovery
  ip arp synchronize

interface port-channel20
  vpc peer-link
```

and this is vpc config for n3k nexus B

```
vpc domain 1
  peer-switch
  role priority 30
  system-priority 120
  peer-keepalive destination 172.x.x.110 source 172.x.x.111
  peer-gateway
  auto-recovery
  ip arp synchronize

interface port-channel20
  vpc peer-link
```

Because I want to have active-active scenario I do not want to use HSRP or VRRP and there are currently 2 questions:

1. on each nexus I am seeing the following log :

> 2020 Oct 15 11:03:02 ATM-N3K-Master %ARP-2-DUP_SRC_IP:  arp [3565]
> Source address of packet received from 24e9.b3xx.xxxx on
> VlanYYYY(port-channel20) is duplicate of local, 185.x.x.x

is it normal ? can i ignore it ?

2. none of my users have any complaint in this scenario but two of my customers told me when they are using ssoftwares such as teamspeak, every 5-10 minutes they have packet resend. I am not sure my users report are correct or not and I do not trust to these users report, so do you think this is related to my network or its from user side?

I was thinking maybe its related to ARP issue because for example this customer has ARP from nexus B for 10minutes and after 10minutes it will get Arp from nexus A but because I want to make sure about this I have put both vlan gateway and user assigned ip (Server IP) under ping for 5-6Hours and there were no packet loss! Whats your idea?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use HSRP?  Its operation with VPC doesn’t pull all traffic to a primary. It instead just determines which switch will normally answer ARP requests (..with the same gateway MAC, of course).

Comment: because i have different ip per vlan for example /30 and also my number of svi will exceed hsrp limit